can not navigate to second page in rdlc
I have a Rdlc report in visual studio 2022 which is designed in Microsoft report builder.
The data should be viewed in 2 pages, the data exist. if I remove page break of the section, it shows all data in one page, but in two pages. I have navigation like this

and when I click for the next page it shows loading and then returns to the first page.
and the setting of second retangle is like this

how should I debug the problem

When you export the report into say a PDF format, does the second page show?

@Harry: yes the PDF and Word are ok.

so if you deploy the report, does it look ok? I've had on and off such issues with no rhyme or reason for it.. but since I know once deployed, they are fine, I don't worry much about it.

@Harry: well I haven't deploy it yet and its proccessmode is local, so you are saying when I deploy it and change the proccessmode to remote it will be ok?

In my case it was / is ok once deployed.
